# Unable to run the spring boot app with spring-boot-starter-parent (2.3.0)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I modified my spring boot starter parent to 2.3.0. With this modification, i also introduced the version in spring maven plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</plugin>
```

I am able to complete `mvn clean install` .. but when i run the command `mvn clean install spring-boot:run` .. i am getting the below error.

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project

Can someone please help.

Entire pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>servicesapp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        
  </parent>
  
  <properties>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.22</slf4j.version>
        <efc.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</efc.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
  </properties>  
    
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->
        
        <!-- For html -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Boot Developer tools  -->
      <!--  <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
             <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency> -->
        
        <!-- test cases -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- helps in monitoring health, metrics, info, dump, env -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
         <!--  Added for Swagger documentation -->
         <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency> -->
           
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
           <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
           <version>2.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m </argLine>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/ServiceMainTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

Complete Error Trace ..

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project webservices-vehiclecontent: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project webservices-vehiclecontent: Application finished with exit code: 1
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm(RunMojo.java:101)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm(AbstractRunMojo.java:296)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:261)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:233)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Show us entire pom.xml

Comment: There is probably something else in the error output - e.g. a stack trace. Please provide the full error.

Comment: @Sergei Updated the original post with the complete error trace

Comment: Looks like the application built successfully but failed during the run stage. Are there any errors above, in the Spring Boot startup logs?

Comment: Again: `pom.xml` is very important here. Can you share it if you wanna be helped?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri i have edited the post to contain pom.xml

Comment: @Sergei no.. i dont see any other errors. I am running in verbose mode -> mvn clean install spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dmaven.test.skip=true -X

Comment: I can only confirm that your pom.xml works fine in a bare project, the application runs without errors. There should be at least some output between the line `[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:run` and this error.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your `pom.xml` and ran `mvn clean install` and after this `mvn spring-boot:run` - everything worked fine and application runs fine.

Try also
`mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage`

Comment: i did see other answers and tried this one and this command is successful.

Comment: What? does this help you or not?

Comment: no .. mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage works .. but mvn clean install spring-boot:run does not work

Comment: Very strange.. I just reproduced your project with all entirely your pom.xml. It worked in any ways, either to run from IntelliJ, or as a Jar standalone, or as `mvn spring-boot:run` after `mvn clean install`.